# Sum of Fourier Series, Sine function to Euler

Tags: fourier-series

This might potentially be one of the dumbest question, but I'm gonna ask anyway.

[view image pls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT4Ua.png)

How do I get $\pi/2$?
I know for a fact $e^{jθ} = cos\theta  + j sin \theta$
but in this case $e^{j3\omega_0t}$... how do I find $\theta$?
Btw period is given as $T_0 = 2\pi/\omega_0$

*I do not know what to put on the title because I am new to this topic, so feel free to offer your suggestions*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, when $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\Re\left[\text{z}\right]=0$ and $\Im\left[\text{z}\right]>0$:

$$\arg\left(\text{z}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi\text{k}$$

Where $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and I worked with radians.

Comment: OMGGGG I KNEW IT WAS EASY BUT I DIDNT KNOW IT WAS THIS EASY!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: @JoeyPeh Hahaha you're welcome, mate :) I'm glad that I could help.